# Using custom model class with Backendless in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I'm trying to retrieve data from an online data storage using the func that I found online on the official Backendless docs! but when I try to use persona like a Lista(my own class) Object, I get the error: Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10c1ccfc0) to 'InLIsta_.Lista' (0x108439790).
I search over this site but the answer aren't specific for the Backendless case, so I hope that anyone can help me

this is my code (obviously I've declared all the var and let necessary to the code to run):

```
class Lista : NSObject {

    var nome: String?
    var pr: String?
    var pagamento = 0
    var entrato: Bool = false
    var commenti: String?
    var objectId: String?
    var created: NSDate?
    var updated: NSDate?
}

func findQ() {

    Types.tryblock({ () -> Void in

        let startTime = NSDate()

        let found = self.backendless.persistenceService.of(Lista.ofClass()).find(self.query)

        let currentPage = found.getCurrentPage()
        print("Loaded \(currentPage.count) name objects")
        print("Total name in the Backendless storage - \(found.totalObjects)")

        for person in currentPage {
            let persona = person as! Lista  // here i get error
            print("Restaurant <\(Lista.ofClass())> name = \(persona.nome)")
            self.nomi.append(persona.nome!)
        }

        print("Total time (ms) - \(1000*NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime))")
        },

                   catchblock: { (exception) -> Void in
                    print("Server reported an error: \(exception as! Fault)")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Obviously according to the error message `currentPage` is an array of dictionaries rather than `Lista` objects

Comment: Have you registered your custom class?

Comment: yes wain i've registered my custom class like explained in the Backendless docs, in fact i can save data in the storage correctly but i can retrieve it! so vadian how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backendless persistence service has a method `-(void)mapTableToClass:(NSString *)tableName type:(Class)type;` that you need to call for each of your custom classes so they'll be used during the deserialisation.

```
self.backendless.persistenceService.mapTableToClass("Lista", type: Lista.self)
```

This needs to be done before any calls are made to use the persistence service.

Note that the classes, if not defined in obj-c, must be exported to obj-c. Note that this also means you can't have any optionals.

Ideally you should use the platform code generation to create your model class definitions to ensure all of the attributes are created with the appropriate types. A failure to map to your custom class could be caused by type mismatches or name mismatches. Optionals will always fail in the current SDK implementation.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand all your information! this is for objective-c?

Comment: The SDK is obj-c and can't deal with all swift features

Comment: so i have to use @objc attribute in my declaration and then to create a bridging header of class in my swift project?

Comment: Backendless provides a bridging header, show your model class in the question

Comment: You need to remove all the optionals, the `?`s

Comment: i've removed it and i have instanced it like this var nome: String = String() but i can't do the call at the method that you gave to me. i wrote: self.backendless.persistenceService.mapTableToClass(Lista.self, type: "Lista") and i get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Lista.Type' to expected argument type 'String!'

Comment: Parameters were in the wrong order (though I thought you said you had registered already)

Comment: i've wrote exactly like your post and i get the error but i thought it was related to a wrong declaration of my class! now it works! thank you a lot